# Responsive design of tailwindcss is too slow

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm making a blog with nextjs and I want to show or hide `TOC`(Table of Contents) responsively.

I'm using tailwindcss but the reaction is too slow.

Is there a solution?

This is my code

```
<div className={`invisible xl:visible`}>
  <TableOfContents />
</div>
```

Problem

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is a transition, possibly with a delay on/in the ToC component.  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-delay

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with display (none xl:block) parameters?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I solved this problem with Gabe's answer.